# spring-boot upgrade to 2.3.1.RELEASE from 2.2.1.RELEASE (got failing tests.)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, upgrade

while upgrading from spring 2.1.2.RELEASE to 2.3.1.RELEASE was facing issues,
the gist of the complete configuration is.
added

```
<spring-boot.version>
       2.3.1.RELEASE
</spring-boot.version>
```

and

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>
        org.springframework.boot
    </groupId>
    <artifactId>
        spring-boot-starter-validation
    </artifactId>
</dependency>
```

keeping the rest of the versions and configs same.
cucumber version -3.0.2
Junit version - 4.12

so after change if we try to run the tests they fail.
we are calling repository's `deleteAll()` method when we see these exceptions in the logs, and if we comment the `saveAndFlush()` method we dont see exceptions.
though this issue is not due to cucumber it seems after some narrowing down that

Appreciate the help also if more info is needed on my specific case I can add details on suggestions.

the code sample is:
FooRepository.java:

```
package com.foo.respositories;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import com.foo.entities.FooEntity;
@Transactional
@Repository
public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<FooEntity, LocalDate> {
    @Modifying
    default void create(FooEntity entity) {
        this.saveAndFlush(entity);
    }
}
```

FooEntity.java:

```
package com.foo.entities;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import lombok.Data;
import org.hibernate.envers.Audited;
@Entity
@Audited
@Data
public class FooEntity {
    @Id
    private LocalDate date;
    private BigDecimal rate;
}
```

the trace of the log is as below.

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: id to load is required for loading; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: id to load is required for loading
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:374)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:257)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible (AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java :528)
at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:178)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy282.deleteAll(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 ( NativeMethodAccessImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy158.deleteAll(Unknown Source)
at *.we clear out database
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: id to load is required for loading
at org.hibernate.event.spi.LoadEvent.<init> (LoadEvent.java:96)
at org.hibernate.event.spi.LoadEvent.<init> (LoadEvent.java:64)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.doLoad(SessionImpl.java:2781)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.lambda$load$1 (SessionImpl.java:2765)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.perform(SessionImpl.java:2721)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2765)
```

Comment: can you paste the error logs and format them properly

Comment: Without seeing the code it is impossible to answer. I doubt that the issue is related to removing the `saveAndFlush`.

Comment: By log I can definitely say that issue is in null value for id field of entities for deleting, but without test code, test config and entity definition is impossible to say where is mistake

Comment: added some logs will add code shortly,
My confusion still holds on one point though how is upgrade causing such issues only in this specific case.

Comment: Is this resolved? @MaryLopez